# Error spotting : The book was so advanced that even graduates in the discipline found it difficult

Tags: exam-questions

> The book was so advanced that even graduates in the discipline found it difficult.

Is the above sentence correct ? My book says I need to add *to understand* after *difficult* because when *difficult* used for predicative purpose it is usually followed by to + Verb first form. Is it true ? Isn't the above sentence correct without *to understand* ?

Comment: The sentence is fine as is.  It might have been difficult to tear in half too, but **advanced** sets the semantic scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Grammatically it is not necessary to add *to understand.***

For comprehension, it could be, but there is enough context in the sentence, it probably doesn't matter.

If you care about the difference between these sentences:

> The book was so advanced that even graduates in the discipline found it difficult to *understand*.
>
> The book was so advanced that even graduates in the discipline found it difficult to *read*.
>
> The book was so advanced that even graduates in the discipline found it difficult to *finish*.

Then it would be helpful to add on the verb.

---

Contrast with a shorter sentence:

> Graduates in the discipline found the book difficult.

Here, there is less context, and therefore a little more ambiguity.

Are the graduate students trying to pick up the heavy book?

> Graduates in the discipline found the book difficult *to lift.*

Are they trying to stop reading the exciting book?

> Graduates in the discipline found the book difficult *to put down*.

Are they embarrassed because it reflects poorly on their field of study?

> Graduates in the discipline found the book difficult *to defend.*

Answer (score 0):

> *The book was so advanced that even graduates in the discipline found it difficult.*
>   *The book was so advanced that even graduates in the discipline found it difficult **to understand***.

The two sentences are grammatically correct.

The **to+verb** form in the second one serves as an adjective complement in order to clarify (meaning) what was the sort of difficulty that graduates found in the book; *....it difficult to understand or to read, for example.*